# Access facebook json response object

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an json response from facebook like this picture.
[image: This is my return json from facebook]

This is the way i tried to access the likes count `data.posts.data[0].likes.count` but it kept showing undefined error and i also tried to access comments object like this `data.posts.data[0].comments.length` it showed the same error. I am stuck here anyone could help me out?

This is my used code to get json

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/128618520547487/?fields=posts.fields(picture,comments,likes,source,link,message)&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAFOZAdI3zIOmKwkCi2tUZCAl2tpuIyh3WuE5B4njTviyzk4msgZCnKBVTNuXh2FQTf4XkfatgVHYer43TTw2kqV2vxHsjNbjbjiUPKToBrCpUP6ZBhVbr00GQTqjcCynzdGHHObe8OwYK7UMXLcZD";
      var data;
      $('.home-blog').append('<img class="lo" src="<?= BASE_PATH ?>img/loader6.gif"/>'); 
      $.getJSON(fburl, function(json){

          }).done(function( data ) {
              $('.lo').remove();

              for(var i = 0;i<10; i++){
                  if(data.posts.data[i].picture != undefined){
                    console.log(data.posts.data[i].likes.count);

                  }
              }
          })
          .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
              $('.lo').remove(); 
              $('.home-blog').append('<div class="home-blog-slot"><h2>Error while loading!!! please Click refresh or F5</h2></div>');
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine when I do it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax("https://graph.facebook.com/128618520547487/?fields=posts.fields(picture,comments,likes,source,link,message)&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAFOZAdI3zIOmKwkCi2tUZCAl2tpuIyh3WuE5B4njTviyzk4msgZCnKBVTNuXh2FQTf4XkfatgVHYer43TTw2kqV2vxHsjNbjbjiUPKToBrCpUP6ZBhVbr00GQTqjcCynzdGHHObe8OwYK7UMXLcZD", {
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: 'callback',
                success: function (json) {
                    console.log(json.posts.data[0].likes.count);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

You MUST use `jsonp` when accessing files that are not on your own server. Please read [sop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: I tried but it does not work the Posts Object contain all the data so I think we could not pass it. I already have conditions to pass the post dont have comments or likes.

Comment: Can you post the exact url that you are using?

Comment: Here it is https://graph.facebook.com/128618520547487/?fields=posts.fields(picture,comments,likes,source,link,message)&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAFOZAdI3zIOmKwkCi2tUZCAl2tpuIyh3WuE5B4njTviyzk4msgZCnKBVTNuXh2FQTf4XkfatgVHYer43TTw2kqV2vxHsjNbjbjiUPKToBrCpUP6ZBhVbr00GQTqjcCynzdGHHObe8OwYK7UMXLcZD

Comment: Make sure that when you are running `file_get_contents`, that you have the `https` wrapper enabled. Trying to get the data without https will results in a error from facebook.

Comment: I am using javascript api so dont think file_get_contents does any help.:(

Comment: How are you getting the data with javascript? I'm sure [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) comes into play and unless you're using JSONP this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31502/discussion-between-duc-phan-and-dave-chen)

Comment: Note that there's a cheeky plugin for chrome that will make the `jsonp` return an empty page. http://puu.sh/3ch8L.png As long as you don't have this plugin it should be fine.

Comment: You were right in the first place. I am very sorry that i did not read your comment carefully. Some posts object does not contain likes object or comments object. that is the reason why it showed undefined.